# pyspark convert dataframe column from timestamp to string of "YYYY-MM-DD" format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In pyspark is there a way to convert a dataframe column of timestamp datatype to a string of format 'YYYY-MM-DD' format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a column with `schema` as

```
root
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Then you can use `from_unixtime` function to convert the *timestamp* to *string* after converting the *timestamp* to *bigInt* using `unix_timestamp` function as

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.withColumn("date", f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(df.date), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

and you should have

```
root
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Hi Ramesh, normally the timestamps are in the form 2012-01-01 00:00:00. Can we format it to Jan-2012 while maintaining it's schema as date: timestamp ? If we use date_format(), we get a string. Which function should we use to format the timestamp in the form we want, while still keeping it as timestamp rather than converting it inadvertently to date: string?

Comment: late to the party, but u can use below code to convert any string to timestamp.
`#udf to change the datatype to timestamp
change_to_timestamp_fmt =  udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'), TimestampType())`

Comment: @anidev711 UDFs in pyspark are usually between 10 and 10000 times slower than native spark (scala/java) functions, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 30):

You can use [date_format](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format) function as below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format

df.withColumn("dateColumn",  date_format(col("vacationdate"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: FYI You can adjust the date format as you need. I needed just month and year so did `yyyy-MM`. Seemed to work OK

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions  import date_format

df.withColumn("DateOnly", date_format('DateTime', "yyyy-MM-dd")).show()
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

one other option to try out will be

from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn('new_time_column', F.to_timestamp(df['Time_column'], 'yyyy-MM-dd'))