# how to convert the date format 'YYYY-MM-DD' to ddMMyy in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, date-format

I tried to convert the date format 2018-07-12 to ddMMyy using to_date but i get null after converting the dateformat

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2018-07-12',)], ['Date_col'])

df = df.withColumn('new_date',to_date('Date_col', 'ddMMyy'))
```

I need to use this logic to convert the dataframe column. I am new to the spark programming and tried lot of solutions but nothing helps.

I need to concat the ddMMyy from one column and hhss from other column

Any help please?

Comment: can you please specify the final output you are looking for?

Comment: the final should be 120718 in the above case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark changing type of column from date to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977360/pyspark-changing-type-of-column-from-date-to-string) and [pyspark convert dataframe column from timestamp to string of “YYYY-MM-DD” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910511/pyspark-convert-dataframe-column-from-timestamp-to-string-of-yyyy-mm-dd-format).

Comment: Also based on the sentence *I need to concat the ddMMyy from one column and hhss from other column*, it seems that this could be an [XY Problem](http://www.xyproblem.info). There may be a better solution but it's hard to tell without seeing a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all let's create DataFrame

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2018-07-12',)], ['Date_col'])
df.show()
```

```
+----------+
|  Date_col|
+----------+
|2018-07-12|
+----------+
```

Then we will define UDF function for that.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


def user_defined_timestamp(date_col):
    _date = datetime.strptime(date_col, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return _date.strftime('%d%m%y')

user_defined_timestamp_udf = F.udf(user_defined_timestamp, T.StringType())
```

And at the end we will apply our functions on DateFrame in order to create column we want.

```py
df = df.withColumn('new_date', user_defined_timestamp_udf('Date_col'))
df.show()
```

```
+----------+--------+
|  Date_col|new_date|
+----------+--------+
|2018-07-12|  120718|
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this I will try it. Just a question.. why are we actually define UDF function for the conversion of date ? Do i need define the function whenever i convert the date?

Comment: You are able to create any function you want using UDF. I don't know if you can use custom timestamp while using `to_date` pyspark function.

Comment: [Do not use a `udf` for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance). You can use [`date_format`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format) as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977360/pyspark-changing-type-of-column-from-date-to-string).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in `pyspark.sql.functions.date_format(date, format)` function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format

df = spark.createDataFrame([('2018-07-12',)], ['dt'])
df.select(date_format('dt', 'ddMMyy').alias('date')).collect()
```

Results:

[image: results]

Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dateformat#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format

Comment: This should be verified answer